# xamDataGrid formatting numeric fields to 4 decimal places

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a WPF project that contains a form with an Infragistics xamDataGrid on it.  The data that is displayed in this xamDataGrid changes depending on the caller.

What I'm trying to do is to format a numeric column (Rate) to display 4 decimal places. I've found several sites with instructions for how to do this with XAML, but since the data in this grid is dynamic, I need to do this in the code-behind. (Preferably C#, but I can manage with VB.NET.)

The caller currently passes me the data to display in the grid as well as which columns to hide and which columns are editable. So I can have it pass me a list of columns to format and the format string to use.

I just need to figure out how to tell the xamDataGrid to format a column or a field in a certain way.

For those of you who want to see the XAML, here it is for the datagrid:

```
<igWPF:XamDataGrid x:Name="GrdMaint"
                   Margin="10"
                   DataSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsDataGrid}}"
                   BorderBrush="Black"
                   BorderThickness="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                   Theme="Office2k7Blue" 
                   GroupByAreaLocation="None" 
                   FieldLayoutInitialized="GrdMaint_OnFieldLayoutInitialized"
                   PreviewMouseDoubleClick="GrdMaint_OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick"
                   RecordUpdated="GrdMaint_RecordUpdated">

    <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
        <igWPF:FieldSettings AllowRecordFiltering="True" 
                             FilterLabelIconDropDownType="MultiSelectExcelStyle" 
                             Width="Auto" />
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>

    <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings HighlightAlternateRecords="True" 
                                   FilterUIType="LabelIcons" 
                                   AllowDelete ="False" 
                                   AutoGenerateFields="True" />
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
</igWPF:XamDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after fighting with the grid and searching for a couple days, I stumbled across the magical search string that found an answer for me.  I found [this post](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/34373/186685.aspx) on the Infragistics support forums (StackOverflow has spoiled me.  It's so much nicer, here.)  And that enabled me to come up with this solution.  In the OnFieldLayoutInitialized event, I can iterate through each of the fields and determine whether or not I want to format that field.  In my case, I'm checking to see if the field name is in a dictionary of field names/format strings.  If so, I apply the format string.

```
private void GrdMaint_OnFieldLayoutInitialized(object sender, FieldLayoutInitializedEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> NumericColumnsToFormat = _Vm.GetNumericColumnFormats(_currentStep);

    foreach (var fld in e.FieldLayout.Fields)
    {
        // apply custom numeric format to specific field, if necessary.
        if (NumericColumnsToFormat.Keys.Contains(fld.Name))
        {
            string formatString = NumericColumnsToFormat[fld.Name];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatString))
            {
                var numberEditorStyle = new Style(typeof(XamNumericEditor));
                numberEditorStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(XamNumericEditor.FormatProperty, formatString));
                fld.Settings.EditorStyle = numberEditorStyle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```